# OMS query language doesnt have a caseinsensitive search option, however i see that it does support REGEX

Tags: azure, oms

OMS query language doesnt have a case insensitive search option, however i see that it does support REGEX.
Regex has a parameter /i to allow case insensitive searches. 
However I am unable to figure out how to use the regex in oms with /i

Does OMS logsearch support /i option at all?
can someone give an example of usage or any other way of achieving a case insensitive search in OMS log search.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn on case sensitivity using the regex mode modifier `(?i)`

for example:

`where string matches regex ("(?i)query")`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
@   Any string of characters.   Computer=RegEx("srv@.contoso.com")  srv01.contoso.com srv02.contoso.com
.   Any single character.       Computer=RegEx("srv...contoso.com") srv01.contoso.com srv02.contoso.com
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/log-analytics/log-analytics-log-searches-regex

Comment: this doesn't address the case sensitive nature of the query. I want my results to include bot srv01 and SRV01

Comment: any string of characters is exactly that.

Comment: If I do a query Computer:Regex("@ABC@") - I get 11Million results whereas Computer:Regex("@abc@") gets me just a few thousand results. I am looking for a way to get a combined result from both, right now i am doing (Computer=*abc* or Computer=*ABC*)

Comment: so? i can't help you with that. you can do [a-cA-C], probably